# docker container connect with remote mysql DB

Tags: mysql, ruby, docker, containers

i have a ruby script inside a docker container, normally this script (without container) is connected with a remote online mysql DB, but when i dockerize it connection with this DB doesn't work.
i tried to change the configuration of this db, i modified port from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0, but nothing.

this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.2.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
WORKDIR home/docker
ADD Gemfile home/docker/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock home/docker/Gemfile.lock
COPY Gemfile /home/dir_project/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /home/dir_project/Gemfile.lock
ADD . /home/docker
RUN bundle install
```

this is my actually configuration take from mysqld.cnf:

```
bind-address = 172.17.0.1 (this is a docker Host IP)
mysqlx-bind-address = 172.17.0.1
```

and this is the database.yml, take from my_project folder:

```
development:
adapter: mysql12
username:....
password:....
host:172.17.0.1
database: my_db
port: 3307
```

but when i try to run the container, this exit with the code 0 without any connection with mysql.

i try also to modify ssh tunnel, which i use to access the db, insert this docker host IP inside the string:

```
ssh -L 3307:172.17.0.1:3306 ... (and link to db)
```

but nothing.

Comment: Where this db is hosted?

Comment: on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I think the questions was more in the line: is it on the same machine or is it a managed service in some cloud provider?

Comment: it is managed service by a provider

Comment: do you suggest me to add the ip addr of this DB in the dockerfile or something like that? for example a connection string? or adjust port in the config file

Comment: if it is managed service by a provider, then check inbound rules of security group for incoming traffic and port

Comment: whereas i connect with mysql server throught tunneling IP for example 3307:127.0.0.1:3306, i try also to connect with my docker host IP, in my case: 3307:172.17.0.1:3306, but doesnt work too

Comment: 3307 is the port of DB provider

Comment: You should be able to use the exact same setup you use without a Docker container.  Nothing you've shown in the question has any mention of database connection information, though.  Can you [edit] the question to include any relevant details, especially including how you're configuring the database connection and what error you're getting when you try to use it?

Comment: i just edit the question

Answer (score 0):

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
correct this line

Comment: i try to delete this line, but the result was the same

Comment: i think that this isnt the problem

Comment: RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get "isntall" -y build-essential spelling mistake  write install

Comment: MySQL database is on the same machine or a managed service in the cloud if port 3306 is exposed and forwarded correctly in your Docker container. Use the container to map ports

Comment: its a write mistake

Comment: th db is a managed service in the cloud when i can access throught IP tunnelling as follow: 3307:127.17.0.1(that is docker host IP):3306

Comment: i try to modify the port connection inside the script and i add: this line: "my_sql = mysql2.new(:host => '172.17.0.1', :database => ''db", and other credential)"